# aggregating duplicates in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel file whose sample looks like the img attached. The highlighted numbers are the duplicate ids which I have. Now column E basically counts the number of days by (C-B) However, I want just one id per row. So for id 55555 the start date is 10/25/2017 and end date should be 1/14/2018 which will now make the number of days to be 61+19=80. However, I am unable to think of a formula which can do this. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Karan Kashyap import & drag down the below formula on column E.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$6=A2),$E$2:$E$6)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dates are numbers, nothing more. They represent the number of days since 31-Dec-1899. All you need is MAXIFS minus MINIFS. If your version of Excel doesn't support MAXIFS or MINIFS then here are some pre-Excel 2016, Office 365 alternatives.

```
'Minimum start date if id = 55555
'option 1 for xl2010 and newer
=AGGREGATE(15, 7, B$2:B$6/(A$2:A$6=A2), 1)
'option 2 for pre-xl2010
=MIN(INDEX(B$2:B$6+(A$2:A$6<>A2)*1E+99, , ))

'Maximum end date if id = 55555
'option 1 for xl2010 and newer
=AGGREGATE(14, 7, C$2:C$6/(A$2:A$6=A2), 1)
'option 2 for pre-xl2010
=MAX(INDEX(C$2:C$6-(A$2:A$6<>A2)*1E+99, , ))
```

I've used `0 \d\a\y\s_)` for a custom number format in column E.

[image]